# GoJS angle of text

Tags: gojs

I'm creating flowcharts using GoJS, and I need to add 'for' loop. There is a hexagon node, which I've rotate using `angle: "90"` but it rotate with text in it. How to set opposite angle for the text in hexagon. I'm working with GoJS for the first time, and not very familiar with it.
Here is the nodeTemplate code.

```js
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
    $(go.Node, 'Spot',
        { locationSpot: go.Spot.Center },
        new go.Binding('location', 'loc', go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
        { selectable: true, selectionAdornmentTemplate: nodeSelectionAdornmentTemplate },
        { resizable: true, resizeObjectName: 'PANEL', resizeAdornmentTemplate: nodeResizeAdornmentTemplate },
        { rotatable: true, rotateAdornmentTemplate: nodeRotateAdornmentTemplate },
        new go.Binding('angle').makeTwoWay(),
        // the main object is a Panel that surrounds a TextBlock with a Shape
        $(go.Panel, 'Auto',
        { name: 'PANEL' },
        new go.Binding('desiredSize', 'size', go.Size.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Size.stringify),
        $(go.Shape, 'Rectangle',  // default figure
            {
            portId: '', // the default port: if no spot on link data, use closest side
            fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: 'pointer',
            fill: 'white',  // default color
            strokeWidth: 2
            },
            new go.Binding('figure'),
            new go.Binding('fill')),
        $(go.TextBlock,
            {
            font: 'bold 11pt Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
            margin: 8,
            maxSize: new go.Size(160, NaN),
            wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
            editable: true
            },
            new go.Binding('text').makeTwoWay())
        ),
        // four small named ports, one on each side:
        makePort('T', go.Spot.Top, false, true),
        makePort('L', go.Spot.Left, true, true),
        makePort('R', go.Spot.Right, true, true),
        makePort('B', go.Spot.Bottom, true, false),
        { // handle mouse enter/leave events to show/hide the ports
        mouseEnter: function(e, node) { showSmallPorts(node, true); },
        mouseLeave: function(e, node) { showSmallPorts(node, false); }
        }
    );
```

And here is the model code:

```js
            model: new go.GraphLinksModel([  // specify the contents of the Palette
            { text: 'Start', figure: 'Circle', fill: '#00AD5F' },
            { text: 'Step' },
            { text: 'If', figure: 'Diamond', fill: 'lightskyblue' },
            { text: 'Loop', figure: 'Hexagon', fill: 'lightpink'/*, angle: '90'*/ },
            { text: 'I/O', figure: 'Parallelogram', fill: 'lightyellow' },
            { text: 'End', figure: 'Circle', fill: '#CE0620' }
        ], [
            // the Palette also has a disconnected Link, which the user can drag-and-drop
            { points: new go.List(/*go.Point*/).addAll([new go.Point(0, 0), new go.Point(30, 0), new go.Point(30, 40), new go.Point(60, 40)]) }
            ])
        });
```

And Hexagon code:

```js
go.Shape.defineFigureGenerator("Hexagon", function(shape, w, h) {
  var points = createPolygon(6);
  var geo = new go.Geometry();
  var fig = new go.PathFigure(points[0].x * w, points[0].y * h, true);
  geo.add(fig);

  for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    fig.add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, points[i].x * w, points[i].y * h));
  }
  fig.add(new go.PathSegment(go.PathSegment.Line, points[0].x * w, points[0].y * h).close());
  freeArray(points);
  geo.spot1 = new go.Spot(.07, .25);
  geo.spot2 = new go.Spot(.93, .75);
  return geo;
});
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show your work and your results, nor did you show what you wanted instead.  Does this do what you want?

```
    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
      $(go.Node, "Auto",
        $(go.Shape, "Hexagon",
          { fill: "white", angle: 90 },
          new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
        $(go.TextBlock,
          { margin: 8 },
          new go.Binding("text"))
      );
```

The "Hexagon" figure Shape is at angle 90, not the Node at angle 90.
[image]

Comment: Looks like, but I don't know in which place I should paste it. I edit my question and add some code. Thanx.

Comment: You should add a **Binding** for **Shape.angle** that either depends on a `data.angle` property or just depends on the `data.figure` property to decide whether to return 90 or 0.

Comment: I add `new go.Binding('Shape.angle', 'angle')` after `new go.Binding('fill')`, but text also turned

Comment: `new go.Binding("angle")`